# System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (Authentication failed, see inner exception.)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono

While making a request to HTTPS server, I am getting following error. Request works with HTTP.

**{System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (Authentication failed, see inner exception.) ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED**

I have set HTTPClientHandler to Android and TLS/SSL Implementation to Native TLD 1.2+ in Android settings.

Comment: Are you using a self-signed cert?

Comment: I do not know what is it. Can you explain plz ?

Comment: a self-signed certificate is a certificate that is not signed by a certificate authority (CA). : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate

Comment: I did not self sign any certificate. I actually did SitePointManager hack to allow HTTPS requests which worked fine but this time it is failing for System.Net.HTTPWebRequest.

Comment: Then most likely you are missing intermediate certificates on the server, it is not configured for forward secret HTTPS, etc... Also why are you manually bypassing the verify process if you have a properly installed and configured cert?

Comment: Earlier, no HttpClient request was working with HTTPS. Then I had to do this work around and it worked for HTTPClient requests. Now it is not working for HTTPWebRequest.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I did it using `WebClient` and than just need add `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`

```
var uri = new UriBuilder("https://url/v3/0").Uri;
var client = new WebClient();
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
    (
       delegate { return true; }
    );    
var content = client.DownloadString(uri);
```

Answer (score -3):

I solved this by adding **ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback** property to HttpWebRequest object like this.

```
HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest(new Uri());
request.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate {return true;}
```

Comment: This method may work but it is not safe. Just sayin..

Comment: Are you sure that `HttpWebRequest` this kind of constructor?